# Swift Stop UIScrollVIew Scrolling When scrollViewDidEndDragging Called

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am attempting to disable scrolling a `UIScrollView` after `scrollViewDidEndDragging` is called. I want the `UIScrollView` to only scroll when the user is scrolling with his/her finger. I haven't found a good way to implement this yet. I have attempting to disable and the enable scrolling, but when I use a flick motion to scroll, the `UIScrollView` continues scrolling. What I have in my code right now is:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(self.contentOffset, animated: false)
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    ... 
}
```

Does anyone know how to immediately stop scrolling if a flick scroll motion is performed?

Comment: i'd subclass the scrollview and make my own `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` function

Comment: @ChrisSlowik it was a duplicate. If I used the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` method and set `targetContentOffset.memory = scrollView.contentOffset` then it works perfect.

Comment: awesome! yea thats a super handy thing to override. i just built a paired scroll view with parallax and used that. glad you got it figured out.